# When navigating to another page, image from previous page is shown for a short amount of time

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, lag

On the login page of the application, I have a small icon. After login, and navigation to another page (login page -> main page -> details page), on the details page, for a split second, the icon from the login page is shown on the details page. I tried hiding it when leaving the login page. I also binded the source of the image to an empty string when navigating from the login page, but nothing seems to do the trick. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The pages are separate xaml pages.

```
<Grid x:Name="ValidationMessage" Visibility ="{Binding ValidationMessageVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}">                       
                    <Image Source="/Assets/LoginError.png" Style="{StaticResource ValidationIconStyle}" Visibility ="{Binding ValidationMessageVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ValidationTextBlock"
                               Text="{Binding ValidationErrorMessage, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               Style="{StaticResource ValidationTextBlockStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Without any code it is hard to answer your question. Are the pages separate xaml pages?

Comment: PLZ PROVIDE US CODE WITH XML FILE

Answer (score 0):

An Idea, since you have not supplied any code is upon navigation from loading screen set a loading view as a popup.
When you then have loaded the page you want to get to, simply call the loaded event and remove the popup there.
If you do not want it to be global you can use the visualTreehelper, to find any open popups and remove them.